# How Can I Unregister Device Using GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've try to Unregister device by gcm using this Code :

```
 btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         GCMRegistrar.unregister(MainActivity.this);
    }
});
```

with knowledge that i used this code in `onCreate()` Method ...
but when i try send a notification to the `DeviceID` the notification Arrives 
that mean the Unregister process didn't success

My `onCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_nn);
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    if (regId.equals(""))
    {
      GCMRegistrar.register(this, "344XXXXXXX571");
    }
    else
    {
      Log.v("Info : ", "Already registered");
    }

     txt.setText(regId);    

     btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

     btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             GCMRegistrar.unregister(MainActivity.this);
        }
    });  
}
```

My LogCat

```
12-25 17:16:31.290: E/Trace(18754): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-25 17:16:31.425: V/Info :(18754): Already registered
12-25 17:16:31.485: D/libEGL(18754): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
12-25 17:16:31.490: D/libEGL(18754): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
12-25 17:16:31.495: D/libEGL(18754): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
12-25 17:16:31.500: D/(18754): Device driver API match
12-25 17:16:31.500: D/(18754): Device driver API version: 10
12-25 17:16:31.500: D/(18754): User space API version: 10 
12-25 17:16:31.500: D/(18754): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Wed Sep 12 17:53:53 KST 2012 
12-25 17:16:31.540: D/OpenGLRenderer(18754): Enabling debug mode 0
12-25 17:16:43.015: D/GestureDetector(18754): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
12-25 17:16:43.020: D/GCMRegistrar(18754): resetting backoff for com.example.test09_gsm
12-25 17:16:43.020: V/GCMRegistrar(18754): Unregistering app com.example.test09_gsm
12-25 17:16:46.865: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(18754): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
12-25 17:16:46.865: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(18754): GCM IntentService class: com.example.test09_gsm.GCMIntentService
12-25 17:16:46.870: V/GCMBaseIntentService(18754): Acquiring wakelock
12-25 17:16:46.895: V/GCMBaseIntentService(18754): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-IntentService-1
12-25 17:16:46.895: E/GCMRegistrar(18754): internal error: retry receiver class not set yet
12-25 17:16:46.895: V/GCMRegistrar(18754): Registering receiver
12-25 17:16:46.895: D/GCMBaseIntentService(18754): handleRegistration: registrationId = null, error = null, unregistered = com.example.test09_gsm
12-25 17:16:46.895: D/GCMRegistrar(18754): resetting backoff for com.example.test09_gsm
12-25 17:16:46.895: V/GCMRegistrar(18754): Saving regId on app version 1
12-25 17:16:46.940: D/onUnregistered(18754): APA91bFrB0pJOQqq7MxSe-so7fbqh70jLpX6bRrcRIdW6py1EuxletPfGr5ZlkytrenbdnJskdWXckjIcHWsvtKXppZ1PsMbhfkzIc9BmX26brIVDTCRSXPey7POA3UqP6EexMD4w_plFQkVy-9pacCqbBfV0k91dQ
12-25 17:16:46.940: V/GCMBaseIntentService(18754): Releasing wakelock
```

please can you help me to unregister the device on GCM 
and don't receive the future notification

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if you are registering receiver to handle your GCM messages. Check `mHandleMessageReceiver`. *I am assuming that you are using the same code as given in documentation.*

But if you don't want to handle unregistered message
Goto `GCMIntentService` class and see onUnregistered method. Remove `displayMessage()` as I commented the line.

```
 @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        //displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {
            ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
        } else {
            // This callback results from the call to unregister made on
            // ServerUtilities when the registration to the server failed.
            Log.i(TAG, "Ignoring unregister callback");
        }
    }
```

This will do your task.

Happy coding :)

Comment: thank you @Pankaj

when I use the code it gives me error in the `ServerUtilities` Class 

`ServerUtilities cannot be resolved`

Comment: Hey... I am not saying that you have to use this code... simply comment that line.

Comment: I mean In this Code `ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);`

should I Create A class ServerUtilities ??

Comment: This class handles the flag and action to unregister the device from your server (NOT from GCM). So if you want to unregister your device from server, you can write your own code.... (You can refer this class to understand how they handles.... remember this class is written for the server which included in documentation code sample). For more info... can you explain your task and your code?

Comment: no , actually i only need to Unregister the Device from the GCM

Comment: Then left empty the `onUnregistered()`. Don't write any code.

Comment: could you Please check this out .
[http://pastie.org/5584241](http://pastie.org/5584241)

I've use the posted code [in the link] but the device still registered to GCM after press the unregistered button and still the Device Received A Push notification ...